# How can I use InMemory database to check records added correctly in a unit test

Tags: c#, unit-testing, entity-framework-core

Using `InMemory` database I'm trying to write a unit test which will check that a method is adding a record to a table. The record gets added in the class under test, but when i try and re-create I'm getting context disposed error. What is the correct way of setting up this test so that I can check the table in memory after the context has been disposed?

**Unit Test**

```
[Fact]
public void Test_AddContact_AddsSuccessfully()
{
    var contextFactoryMock = new Mock<IContextFactory>();
    contextFactoryMock.Setup(x => x.CreateContext()).Returns(CreateInMemoryContactContext());

    var classUnderTest = new AddContact(contextFactoryMock.Object); 

    var response = classUnderTest.Run(new UkContactUsDto());

    using (var ctx = contextFactoryMock.Object.CreateContext()) 
    {
        var items = ctx.ContactUs.ToList(); //<--- Exception happens here due to ctx being disposed
    }
}
```

**Create InMemory method**

```
private ContactContext CreateInMemoryContactContext()
{
    var _inMemoryContext = new ContactContext(new DbContextOptionsBuilder<ContactContext>().UseInMemoryDatabase((Guid.NewGuid().ToString())).Options);
    
    return _inMemoryContext;
}
```

**Method im testing**

```
try
{
    await using var ctx = _contextFactory.CreateContext();
    ctx.ContactUs.Add(contactUs);
    ctx.SaveChanges();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    log.LogInformation(ex,"An error occured during contact us insertion.");
    throw;
}
```

**Error Message**

> Cannot access a disposed context instance. A common cause of this
> error is disposing a context instance that was resolved from
> dependency injection and then later trying to use the same context
> instance elsewhere in your application. This may occur if you are
> calling 'Dispose' on the context instance, or wrapping it in a using
> statement. If you are using dependency injection, you should let the
> dependency injection container take care of disposing context
> instances.

Comment: I think your unit test the class under test will use different contextes here. your factory will create two different context.

i'd try to generate a context first (`using ctx = contextFactoryMock.Object.CreateContext()), then mock the factory with: `contextFactoryMock.Setup(x => x.CreateContext()).Returns(ctx);`

then to check the added contacts, check with your initial ctx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are disposing the context in the method you are testing so you can't then use it again. One way round it is to create a new context, but you will need to manually keep track of a [`InMemoryDatabaseRoot`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.storage.inmemorydatabaseroot?view=efcore-5.0) instance. For example:

```
private static readonly _memoryDatabaseRoot InMemoryDatabaseRoot = new InMemoryDatabaseRoot();

private ContactContext CreateInMemoryContactContext()
{
    var _inMemoryContext = new ContactContext(new DbContextOptionsBuilder<ContactContext>()
        .UseInMemoryDatabase("my-database", _memoryDatabaseRoot).Options);
    
    return _inMemoryContext;
}
```

Now in your test you can call `CreateInMemoryContactContext` to get a new context that uses the same in-memory database instance

Note: You may not want the root to be static if you're going to use it in multiple tests.

Comment: is this meant to be private static readonly InMemoryDatabaseRoot _memoryDatabaseRoot = new InMemoryDatabaseRoot();

Comment: With  `static`, the data will be reused in each test. If you want a new sample data for each test, you can remove the `static`.

Comment: @JsonStatham It doesn't need to be `static`, you just need to make sure you use the same instance for the test when you create a new context. You can kinda consider the root object as your database if that helps your thinking.

Answer (score 2):

In the Mock, the method `CreateContext` is mocked with a instance of `DbContext`. The Mock return the same instance for all call to `CreateContext`. You can check with this test :

```
var context = CreateInMemoryContactContext();
var contextFactoryMock = new Mock<IContextFactory>();
contextFactoryMock.Setup(x => x.CreateContext()).Returns(context);
Assert.ReferenceEquals(context, contextFactoryMock.Object.CreateContext());
```

In think `AddContact` dispose the context. When you reuse the context to do assertion, the context is disposed.

You need pass a factory in `Returns` like :

```cs
var contextFactoryMock = new Mock<IContextFactory>();
contextFactoryMock.Setup(x => x.CreateContext()).Returns(CreateInMemoryContactContext);
```

To conserve data between context, you need reuse the same DbOption when you create new DbContext. With xunit, for each test a instance of test class is instancied. You can put the initialization part in the constructor :

```cs
public class AddContactTest
{
    private DbOptions _dbOptions;

    public AddContactTest()
    {
        _options = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<ContactContext>().UseInMemoryDatabase((Guid.NewGuid().ToString())).Options
    }

    private ContactContext CreateInMemoryContactContext()
    {
        var _inMemoryContext = new ContactContext(_dbOptions);
        return _inMemoryContext;
    }

    [Fact]
    public void Test_AddContact_AddsSuccessfully()
    {
        var contextFactoryMock = new Mock<IContextFactory>();
        contextFactoryMock.Setup(x => x.CreateContext()).Returns(CreateInMemoryContactContext);

        var classUnderTest = new AddContact(contextFactoryMock.Object); 

        var response = classUnderTest.Run(new UkContactUsDto());

        using (var ctx = contextFactoryMock.Object.CreateContext()) 
        {
            var items = ctx.ContactUs.ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: But doing this will create a new context when it comes time to test a record was inserted, and with the in-memory database, the data will have gone.

Comment: This is correct, as i have tried and the contact us table is empty

Comment: I miss this part... You can open and close context without loss data, but you need use the same `DbOptions`. But the method `CreateInMemoryContactContext` create a new `DbOption`.  I will edit my answer.